# нарезать на строки сообщение

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

У меня есть переменная с сообщение:

```
text = "ff\ndd"
```

Как мне нарезать это сообщение на новые строки, то есть на `ff` и `dd`
Чтобы было к примеру

```
["ff","dd"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Использовать стандартную функцию str.split

```
text.split('\n')
```

Comment: А если у меня будет так «aa\nbb\ncc». Как мне нарезать и кинуть в массив arr = [“aa”,”bb”,”cc”] ?

Comment: так выше написано же

Answer (score 1):

используйте метод `split`

```
arr = text.split('\n')
```

Comment: А если у меня будет так «aa\nbb\ncc». Как мне нарезать и кинуть в массив arr = [“aa”,”bb”,”cc”] ?

Answer (score 1):

```
new_text = text.split('\n')
```

Очень простая к пониманию статья про работу со строками
https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html

Comment: А если у меня будет так «aa\nbb\ncc». Как мне нарезать и кинуть в массив arr = [“aa”,”bb”,”cc”] ?

Comment: все точно так же `arr = string.split('\n')`.  метод split("") - служит для разбиения строки по разделителю. разделитель указывается в (""). В данном случае разделитель - "\n".